# uploading image with firebase admin sdk on node js

Tags: c#, android, node.js, firebase, base64

[image: #]

so im trying to upload a picture from a mobile device to firebase storage and have tried many ways and cant seem to do it. heres my code below

front end C#

this is the activity where i get the picture

```
 namespace Kula
   {
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Addprofilepicture : ContentPage
    {
        ImageButton imagebutton;
        Label basse64;
        IMyAPI myAPI;
        APIRequestHelper apiRequestHelper;
        public Addprofilepicture()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            imagebutton = this.FindByName<ImageButton>("addprofilepicture");
            basse64 = this.FindByName<Label>("base64");
            myAPI = RestService.For<IMyAPI>("http://10.0.2.2:8080");
            apiRequestHelper = new APIRequestHelper(myAPI);
        }
        private async void addprofilepicture_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoPickerService>().GetImageStreamAsync();          
            if (stream != null)
            {
                ImageSource Image;
                byte[] b = ReadFully(stream);
                String s = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
                Image = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromStream(
                () => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(s)));
                imagebutton.Source = Image;
                basse64.Text = (stream).ToString();    
                Postbase(b);             
            }      
        }
        public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        public async void Postbase(byte[] bytearray) {
            base64s s = new base64s()
            {
                base64string = bytearray

            };
            string stringpayload =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);
            await myAPI.PostProfilePhoto(s);         
        }
      public  class base64s { 
          public byte[] base64string { get; set; }       
        }
    }
  }
```

this is where i send it to my local port

```
    [Post("/addprofilepicture")]
        Task<string> PostProfilePhoto(base64s s);

this is where my backend receives it (node js now)

app.post('/addprofilepicture', (request, response) =>{
  console.log('request tried')
   REQUEST_DATA = request.body;
  if(REQUEST_DATA!== null){
      console.log(/*REQUEST_DATA +*/ 'userdatasaved');
      REQUEST_IDTOKEN = REQUEST_DATA.idtoken;
      REQUEST_EMAIL = REQUEST_DATA.email;
      REQUEST_IMAGEBASE64 = REQUEST_DATA.fullname;  
      firebaseHelper1.Photo( REQUEST_IMAGEBASE64, storage);   
  }
  else{
  console.log('request was null');
  };
});
```

and here is where it attemps to put it in firebase (where all the errors occured)

```
Photo(base64, ref){
    admin.ref.upload(base64,{
        destination: 'UsersImages/',
      
        gzip: true,
        metadata: {
          cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000'
        }
      }).then(() => {
        console.log(`${filename} uploaded.`);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
      });
    
    }

ive also tried this method  

       Photo(base64, ref){ 
ref.putString(ref, 'base64').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Uploaded a base64 string!');
});
    };
```

initializing firebase database and storage

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: 'https://kula-fb8b3.firebaseio.com/',
  storageBucket: "gs://kula-fb8b3.appspot.com"
  });
  let db = admin.firestore();
  
  var storage = admin.storage().bucket();
```

what happens is it keeps saying these functions dont exist such as

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'putString' of undefined
    at FirebaseHelper.Photo (C:\Users\general morgan\Desktop\Backend code\KulaaBackend\FirebaseHelper.js:88:5)
    at C:\Users\general morgan\Desktop\Backend code\KulaaBackend\Main.js:58:23
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\general morgan\Desktop\Backend code\KulaaBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\general morgan\Desktop\Backend code\KulaaBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\general morgan\Desktop\Backend code\KulaaBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\general morgan\Desktop\Backend code\KulaaBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\general morgan\Desktop\Backend code\KulaaBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\general morgan\Desktop\Backend code\KulaaBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\general morgan\Desktop\Backend code\KulaaBackend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\general mo
```

some useful information is the connection to firebase is fine. i can create accounts, upload profile information from the phone all the way to firebase database all using firebase admin. but firebase storage ive been trying to figure out for a while now. also i can do a console.log(base64) and it will print to the console so it go sent just fine. any help would be amazing

Comment: What is storage in firebaseHelper1.Photo( REQUEST_IMAGEBASE64, storage);

Comment: @SharathHolla REQUEST_IMAGEBASE64 is part of the json body that just got sent over the part i needed the base64 string. storage is a firebase bucket i added the code above to show how i made it.

Comment: storageBucket: "gs://kula-fb8b3.appspot.com"
The above line doesn't look right. It should be "https://kula-fb8b3.appspot.com" or just "kula-fb8b3.appspot.com"

Comment: @SharathHolla that wasnt it i just tried it with the same error popping up:(